# Using a loop to re-generate JFrame

Tags: java, swing, loops, jframe, jbutton

So I have this program that generates a random description of your company.

This is mainly used for link building websites etc. so you don't have duplicate data. I added a Button to the `JFrame` so that when pressed it will re-scramble the sentence instead of exiting the program and fill out all the information again.

I have been trying to use groups but can't seem to figure it out.  Any ideas?

I don't want the program to ask for the information again so I would need the loops to start where the random variable thing begins.

```
if (actionCommand.equals("Product")) {

    JButton Pbutton;
    Pbutton = new JButton("Generate");
    final String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your Business name: \n \n ex: We at 'your business' deliver...");
    final String productP = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your Business product(plural): \n \n ex: take pride in our 'pizza slicers'");
    final String productS = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your Business product(singular): \n \n ex: we make the highest quality 'pizza slicer' in...");
    final String location = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Where is your business located? \n \n ex: Cityville, Virginia.");
    final String keywords = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter 6 keywords for your product: \n \n Ex: pizza, pizza slicer, cityville, Virginia, tools, restaurant equipment");
    final String URL = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your website URL: \n \n ex: www.yourwebsite.com");

    Random rand1 = new Random();
    int number1 = rand1.nextInt(3);

    if (number1 == 2)
      v1 = "We at ";
    else if (number1 == 1)
      v1 = "The staff at ";
    else if (number1 == 0)
        v1 = "The professionals at ";

    Random rand2 = new Random();
    int number2 = rand2.nextInt(5);

    if (number2 == 4)
      v2 = " take great pride in our ";
    else if (number2 == 3)
      v2 = " know the importance of having great ";
    else if (number2 == 2) 
      v2 = " bring you only the best ";
    else if (number2 == 1) 
        v2 = " offer only the greatest ";
    else if (number2 == 0) 
        v2 = " are bringing you top-of-the-line ";

    Random rand3 = new Random();
    int number3 = rand3.nextInt(5);

    if (number3 == 4)
      v3 = "  We offer the highest quality " + productS + " ";
    else if (number3 == 3)
      v3 = "  Let us be the ones to supply you with " + productP + " ";
    else if (number3 == 2)
      v3 = " No one can compete with our high quality " + productP + " ";
    else if (number3 == 1)
      v3 = " Only we can offer these a " + productS + " of this quality ";
    else if (number3 == 0)
      v3 = " Turn to us if you need a " + productS + " ";

    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame(name);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(JMUpurple);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 3));

    String text = v1 + name + v2 + productP + "." + v3 + "in " + location + ".";

    String text2 = name + " of " + location + "| High quality " + productP;

    String text3 = keywords;

    String text4 = URL;

    Font font = new Font("Georgia", 0, 12);

    JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea(text, 5, 25);
    JTextArea textArea2 = new JTextArea(text2, 5, 25);
    JTextArea textArea3 = new JTextArea(text3, 10, 25);
    JTextArea textArea4 = new JTextArea(text4, 2, 25);
    textArea2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    textArea3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea1, 22, 
      32);
    JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(textArea2, 22, 
      32);
    JScrollPane scrollPane3 = new JScrollPane(textArea3, 22, 
      32);
    JScrollPane scrollPane4 = new JScrollPane(textArea4, 22, 
      32);
    textArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea2.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea2.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea3.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea3.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea4.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea4.setLineWrap(true);
    frame.add(scrollPane);
    frame.add(scrollPane2);
    frame.add(scrollPane3);
    frame.add(scrollPane4);
    frame.add(Pbutton);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    textArea1.setFont(font);
    textArea1.setBackground(JMUgold);
    textArea2.setFont(font);
    textArea2.setBackground(JMUgold);
    textArea3.setFont(font);
    textArea3.setBackground(JMUgold);
    textArea4.setFont(font);
    textArea4.setBackground(JMUgold);

}
```

Comment: somewhat large chunk of code, any more hints?

Comment: Yea I don't have a ton of experience writing Java, self taught so I do some things probably very inefficiently.  Sorry about the large amount of code.  I just need to repaint the Jframe somehow while retaining the String data at the beginning, but re-generating the random variables.

Comment: When variable names are similar except for a number, you should look at using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

### Refactor

Your code is mostly written in procedural style. You should **break it into small chunks and put them in methods**.

---

The minimum requirement here would be to **have random generation code wrapped in a method** which takes `JTextBox`es as argument.

This method should call `setText` on them in stead of creating them. You should create them without any text at start and keep a private global reference in the class.

This makes sense even from the view that it separates UI instantiation from any business logic. You can call this method safely any times now.

---

**Note:**
If you are going to refactor it, it might be a nice idea to consider moving all the strings outside the source code. It's generally considered a good practice to have them in a xml file or something.

They contain no logic, they should not be in source. Also it greatly affects readability of your code (since you have lot of them). You would even find a boost in maintainability of your code.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you guys for your detailed comments, I will look into breaking this into methods!

Answer (score 0):

Is this your first experience with object-oriented programming languages?  While you can store all the variables locally, as you attempted, creating objects and storing relevant information in separate objects is almost always a better idea.  Additionally, as Tanmay mentioned in another answer, breaking work down into methods increases both readability and reusability.

To solve this, I would use three classes:

1) Create a class to store the appropriate strings.  Have a method (or four) in this class that returns the appropriately randomized strings for each box.  (I will call this the `BusinessInfo` class.)  If you do choose keep the strings hard-coded (which, as Tanmay mentions, is not generally a good idea), then you would keep them here.

2) Create a class that overrides `JPanel`.  Have this class store four `JTextBox` objects.   In the constructor, use those `JTextBox`es to display information.  Add four methods for setting the text in those `JTextBox` objects.

3) In the `JFrame` class, before showing the frame, create the `BusinessInfo` object.  (Using `JOptionPane`s is not a bad idea here.)  Create the custom `JPanel` and call its four set methods.  Add that panel, and another panel containing a reset button, to the `JFrame`.  Add a new `randomize()` method that is called when the reset button is pressed.  Have the randomize method call the four set methods on the custom `JPanel`.

This is a rudimentary, off-the-cuff idea of how I'd break it down.  It is just one example of many that could work.

Hopefully, this and other answers can get you moving in the right direction.  If you think you have refactored the code adequately, and would like to have others review it, try using the [code review stack exchange site.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Related reading: [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)